# how to use push storyboards without hiding navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller

I am building an iOS app using **storyboards**. I integrated Facebook in my app.

I'm facing a problem after successful login via Facebook and user close the app and come 
again,i want it should be on a particular screen.

I implemented push storyboard code but when user come on that screen navigation bar hides 
which is my problem.

Could someone help me how I can handle this.

here is my code:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{

    PlayNext *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Play"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];

     }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. It sounds like you want the navigation bar to be visible. If that's true, why are you hiding it?

Comment: @rdelmar i have edited my code please check

Comment: I can handled this by using code    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];   but now my tab bar hides.

Comment: Can you use segue ? [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Play" sender:self];

Comment: same is happening when i'm using seague.